# Taking real and imaginary parts after reciprocal

Tags: complex, assumptions

I noticed the following strange scenario. When I defined a variable to be real, Mathematica does not only recognize that it is real after taking an inverse. How can I resolve this so that it will recognize 1/x is still real?

```
In[29]:= $Assumptions = {x ∈ Reals}

Out[29]= {x ∈ Reals}

In[30]:= Im[x]

Out[30]= Im[x]

In[31]:= Refine[Im[x]]

Out[31]= 0

In[32]:= Refine[Re[x]]

Out[32]= x

In[33]:= Refine[Im[1/x]]

Out[33]= Im[1/x]

In[34]:= Refine[Re[1/x]]

Out[34]= Re[1/x]
```

Comment: Another way to do it is use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) without any assumptions.  For example:  `$Assumptions = True;  ReIm[ 1 / x ] // ComplexExpand`

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 7):

If `x=0`, then `1/0` is `ComplexInfinity`. If you add the assumption that `x!=0`, then you get what you are wanting:

```
 Assuming[{b \[Element] Reals, b != 0}, Refine[Im[1/b]]]
```

> ```
>    0
> ```